# How to extract lat/long from a shape file programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt, latitude-longitude, shapefile

I successfully created an application using **Qt** and [shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) library to open and display **[shape files](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shapefile)**.

But now I want to get the **latitude** and **longitude** of every point under the mouse cursor.

I don't know how to convert a point in pixel that is some thing like `(x, y)` to lat/log coordinates.

Should I use **.dbf** file?

Any reference would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: From reading the reference you provided, I cannot definitely say geographic latitude and longitude are stored in these files. It seems to me they are not.

Comment: @Jongware Maybe! but when I open a .shp file with something like QGis it does have lat/long ! I'm totally confused.

Comment: `dbf` files are simply for storage.  You'll need to figure out how to convert the mouse coordinates to corresponding `shapefile` coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use QGIS. If you use QGIS, you can have a `QGsMapCanvas` which has a signal named `xyCoordinates(QgsPoint)` and is emitted when the mouse is moved on the map. `QgsPoint` could be converted to lat/long using a function  named `toString`  or to other units like degree/minutes/seconds using `toDegreesMinutesSeconds` :

```
connect(map,SIGNAL(xyCoordinates(QgsPoint)),this,SLOT(showMouseCoordinate(QgsPoint)));

void GIS::showMouseCoordinate(const QgsPoint &p)
{

    if ( map->mapUnits() == QGis::DegreesMinutesSeconds )
    {
        ui->coordinateLbl->setText( p.toDegreesMinutesSeconds( 3 ) );
    }
    else
    {
        ui->coordinateLbl->setText( p.toString( 3 ) );
    }
}
```